# About render pass compatibility in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I read the portion relevant to "Render Pass Compatibility" in Vulkan specification. I'm not sure if my understanding is right.

Record some commands inside a render pass, which exists the invocation of VkFrameBuffer and VkPipeline. VkFrameBuffer or VkPipeline is strongly related to VkRenderPass. They must only be used with that render pass object, or one compatible with it. Can I reuse VkFrameBuffer or VkPipeline in a compatible render pass? Tell me more about this topic, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what do with your question except answer "yes".

`VkRenderPassBeginInfo` VU:

> `renderPass` **must** be **compatible** with the `renderPass` member of the `VkFramebufferCreateInfo` structure specified when creating `framebuffer`.

e.g. `vkCmdDraw` VU:

> The current render pass **must** be **compatible** with the `renderPass` member of the `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo` structure specified when creating the `VkPipeline` bound to `VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS`.

I.e. the `VkFramebuffer` resp. `VkPipeline` has to be used with render pass that is "only" compatible, not necessarily the same object handle.